# Saving failed requests to try again later?

Tags: vue.js, npm, electron

I am writing a electron-vue desktop application to upload form data to google sheets. Everything is working when I have internet connection. The problem is to handle things silently when there is no internet connection or if the request fails for some other reason.

I have tried to look for npm's that can save data locally (encrypted if possible) and asynchronously try whenever there is success.I posted in npm forums https://npm.community/t/saving-failed-requests-to-try-again-later/6830 but no luck still

I am looking for something that can save the data locally and retry it when connection is available again without any user input.

Answer (score 0):

You could try simple hack here

make use of setInterval to send data for a certain duration and once data is sent, call clearInterval. That's all!

code sample synax

```
save= ()=>{
  setInterval(update(data) , 10000)
}

  update= (data)=>{
    //onSucess()
    clearInterval();

}
```

Comment: Will this work in case the other person closes the app?

Comment: if the app is closed it will not work. If it is minimized you could handle it in the background task.

Comment: that is the problem here. This will be a desktop app which means the app will be closed , computer restarted and who other host of things.